# Android - do sensors return values in xyz or zxy?

Tags: android

I want to use some sensors in the device, logically I presume the values returned from a SensorListener `event.values` are returned as:
`float[] xyz = event.values`
But I've seen lots of places where people say they're returned as:
`float[] zxy = event.values`

So when I'm getting values is values[0] the X-axis or the Z-axis?
The documentation doesn't specify specifically:
`Measures degrees of rotation that a device makes around all three physical axes (x, y, z).`
`// Many sensors return 3 values, one for each axis.`

So how are they returned? XYZ, ZXY or something else?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
All values are in SI units (m/s^2)
values[0]: Acceleration minus Gx on the x-axis
values[1]: Acceleration minus Gy on the y-axis
values[2]: Acceleration minus Gz on the z-axis
```

Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html

Comment: Honestly don't know how I missed this. I've seen so many wrong answers on this site (that have been accepted) that don't follow this rule.

Comment: Just dived through the documentation: `When it returns, the array values is filled with the result: 

values[0]: azimuth, rotation around the Z axis. 
values[1]: pitch, rotation around the X axis. 
values[2]: roll, rotation around the Y axis. 
`

Comment: Yes, it depends on which sensor you are using. Its all there.